# Should a (copy) @property be released? Is Apple's sample code correct?

Tags: cocoa, ios, memory-management

This question is refers to Apple's example "TableSearch" project that implements a searchable table view. The relevant source code can be found here:

[MainViewController.h](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Listings/MainViewController_h.html)

[MainViewController.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Listings/MainViewController_m.html)

In this example project, the "MainViewController" class has a property to save the search term:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *savedSearchTerm;
```

But the dealloc does not release "savedSearchTerm":

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [listContent release];
    [filteredListContent release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

(The example code doesn't release the "savedSearchTerm" anywhere else (although it does set it to nil under some circumstances in viewDidLoad)).

Given that Apple's memory management rules say that you should release objects created using “alloc”, “new” or “copy”, why doesn't "savedSearchTerm" need to be released?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be released in the `-dealloc` method.  If the sample code is not doing that, please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the sample, but as you describe it, saveSearchTerm needs to be released.

either via

```
self.saveedSearchTerm = nil;
```

or

```
[savedSearchTerm release];
```

if you see simply

```
savedSearchTerm = nil;
```

then this is likely a memory leak as it is just setting the ivar to nil without releasing the object.

Comment: You should not use the setter in the `dealloc` code.  The proper way to do this is to release the ivar directly.

Comment: @Dave Delong - what's the rationale for this?  Can you point me to some docs?

Comment: @Dave Apple docs show both ways and even say you have to use the property setter on newer runtimes (which I think is now false..).  Also, while it could be argued that this is not desirable or good, releasing the ivar will bypass the KVO process for that property.  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html

Comment: @TomSwift: that's exactly the point; invoking methods in dealloc can trigger unwanted side effects, *especially* if you have other objects observing the object being deallocated.  By using the setter, you may be triggering KVO notifications to fire, which will trigger the observers, who may try to access a partially deallocated object and be expecting a certain object state.  If that state is not present, or the data that they're trying to access no longer exists, then Bad Things can happen.

Comment: @TomSwift: This isn't as much of a problem in your own app (as long as you're careful!), but if you work on any sort of publicly-available code (github or a framework or whatever) it's something you need to be keenly aware of.

Comment: @Dave Delong - I'd argue then that "proper" is a bit strong.  Agreed that releasing the ivar is safer.